# How to create macro that will run on All new spreadsheets on Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, macros

All I want to do is set up a simple macro that will take any opened spreadsheet, sort on three fields (e.g. column 1 then 2 then 4), remove the header line and then remove all columns from E onwards.

So I hit, say, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, and the above happens.

Setting up the macro is easy but the key issue here is that it needs to work on **any** spreadsheet I open on that Mac.

The problem I see at the moment is that the Macro that is set up references the spreadsheet that was open when I set it up so it fails on any **other** spreadsheet with an 'out of range' error.

For example, the auto created macro says:

```
Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FirstSheet.csv").Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

So when I close `FirstSheet.csv` and open `Secondsheet.csv`, the macro fails as it's trying to sort `FirstSheet.csv`.

Can anyone guide me here please?